# Mongorestore in gz file

Tags: mongodb, dump, mongorestore

I'm trying use mongorestore with gz file:

i've the following directory:

```
__/tmp/bkp/dbbkp
   |__ collection1.bson
   |__ collection1.metadata.json
   |__ collection2.bson
   |__ collection2.metadata.json
   |__ collection3.bson
   |__ collection3.metadata.json
```

and i'm using
tar -cvzf /tmp/bkp/dbbkp.gz /tmp/bkp/dbbkp/*

and now i've the following files

```
__/tmp/bkp/dbbkp/
__/tmp/bkp/dbbkp.gz
```

now i want

> mongorestore --gzip --archive=/tmp/bkp/dbbkp.gz

but i get this message

> Failed: stream or file does not appear to be a mongodump archive

how can i use mongorestore in dbbkp.gz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongorestore does not read tar files.  It can only read archives created by mongodump.

With that example tar, you would need to extract the files first, then run mongo restore on the directory.

Comment: do you know if exist one way to convert my directory with bson files, to mongodump .gz?

Comment: You would need to un-tar that archive to a directory, use mongorestore to import that directory to a mongodb, and then use mongodump with the --archive option to re-export it.

Comment: thanks man, it works!